# batch to exe virus detected, solution or alternative way

Tags: windows, batch, virus, anti-virus

After converting the batch(.bat) file to .exe file using Bat To Exe Converter, the .exe file is detected as Trojan Virus. 
The sample batch file:

```
@echo off
if exist "myexe.exe" START myexe.exe -password
Exit
```

I created an invisible 32 bit output. Once with UPX compression and once without it. Both of them are tested via VirusTotal.com. Over 25 AVs detected both as virus.

I want to give this EXE to many people that may have different AntiViruses and want they run it without problem.
This is a false positive indeed. What is your solution? or another alternative way?

---

more explaine:

Actually I need a exe launcher and I don't want the users know path of exe and password. So, launcher should be invisible and has not any problem with antivirus.

Comment: Arguably, it sounds as if you will simply need to experiment with different approaches. There are other languages besides batch (some of which can be turned into `.exe` files), such as Python or C++. Or you could investigate small utilities designed to hide the execution  of a program. But it's hard to recommend an approach that would be suitable for a random set of anti-virus programs without hands-on experience.

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT : I need a exe launcher to start main exe.

Comment: @Anaksunaman: I don't want to hide main exe (in my case: myexe.exe). I just want to hide path of myexe.exe and his parameter (password). So, I want the launcher has not console window. Bat To Exe Converter works fine, but output file is detected as virus on some antiviruses.

Comment: @AliM67 .... So are you really looking for a solution that will *"convert a batch to an EXE compiling in a fashion that it's not detectable as a false-negative virus"* or do you need *"to pass a password value to an executable and keep that value from being easily view able"*? If you're available and want to talk about it more, I may be able to help you if we can maybe chat for a few minutes. I will create a chat and send you a link if so. Hit me up if so and I'll see if I can get you a workable solution, but we're gonna have to talk more like in a chat when you and I both have time.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are looking for that is but something Windows Native would be the least likely to cause you virus type problems when running on a Windows OS.

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT : Thank you for your reply. I'm ready to chat please.

Comment: Let's have a cool [Chat Discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96628/discussion-between-pimpjuiceit-and-alim67)

Comment: I think I have not enough reputation to chat.

Comment: Thanks but it says I need 20 reputations on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96629/discussion-between-pimp-juice-it-and-alim67).

Comment: I don't seem to have this issue using Bat To Exe Converter 3.2.0.0 by Faith Kodak.